# Need Help with Error :- Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error
>   occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code
>   returned from the server was: 0 [Break On This Error]
>   this._endPostBack(this._cr...er.get_statusCode()), sender, null);

I am using Telerik's radcontrols like radgrid, radcombobox on my aspx pages. The problem that I am facing is that if I leave my page idle for a while , say even for 2 minutes, it sometimes becomes really slow or it just hangs! Now I am wondering of it is the viewstate used in pages that is causing the issue or is it because if the heavy radgrid controls or it is because of this weird error that I have mentioned above.

Sometimes the page would work fine but at other times, the Radgrid (if used on page) just stops working and I am unable to add /edit my data.

What's wrong? please shed some light on the error above. Also, I would like to know how I can get rid of this erro and if this is what is the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code this can be very tricky to figure out. However, since you suspect that this is a Telerik issue what would be best is if you submit a sample project replicating the issue to [Telerik support](http://www.telerik.com/support).